Why does Microsoft Word open a file as "Read Only"?
I have recently migrated from a MacBook Pro (Intel) to a Mac Mini M2 running macOS Sonoma 14.5.
When I launch MS Word and select a file from the Recent section of the "Home" screen, the file opens as "Read Only". If I double-click the file from its location in my OneDrive folder, it opens will full access. If the file is located in my Desktop folder, I have full access in both situations (Recent section and double-clicking).
I also tried this with MS Excel and the same things happen. I checked Privacy & Security > Files and Folders for Word, Excel, and OneDrive and each has proper permissions.
I logged out of OneDrive and MS Word and then logged back in with the same behavior.
Prior to migration, I did not have this problem. Of course, there have been some updates to the OneDrive app since then.
What is causing this and how can I remedy it?
MS Word: 16.85.2 (24052614)
OneDrive: 24.097.0513 (24097.0513.0001)

